# how to find all neighboring graph vertices that share two common neighbors

Tags: graph-theory

I need to find a fast way to solve the following graph problem.

I have a graph with two types of vertices in it (illustrated by circles and squares in the picture).
I wish to find all edges between two squares, which have the following property:
Both of the two square vertices making up this edge needs to share a connection to at least two circle vertices. Meaning that the two squares needs to have two circular neighbors in common.

I have added two illustrations to showcase what my graphs might look like. The first illustration is a graph where there are no connections fulfilling the criteria I'm looking for, while in the second illustration the connection between the two right-most squares fulfill the criteria.

[image: A graph without the connections I'm looking for]

[image: A graph with the connection I'm looking for]

Does anyone have a good idea about how I might solve such a problem? I am currently using python igraph, but any help would be appreciated, or even just a pointer in the direction of graph theory concepts you think might be useful for me in order to solve this problem.
(While I have a background in mathematics, I never did take graph theory, which I regret now)

Edit:

The problem I'm trying to solve is to calculate the potential moves for a piece in a boardgame called hive.
The pieces live on a hexagonal grid, and this particular piece can move adjacent to any other piece, provided it can fit through. A boardgame state is shown in the picture below and the particular piece I'm trying to calculate the movement for is selected. The green hexagons highlight potential movement places, note how the 3 hexagons at the top hole are not highlighted, this is because the piece cannot fit through the hole going into that place. Finding those choke points where the piece cannot enter is exactly the problem I'm trying to solve.
I already have a recursive function that goes through each position and checks all neighbors for potentially valid moves (this method uses an axial grid). This method works, but it is slow, so I'm hoping for a faster option using graph theory. (My current recursive option is responsible for roughly 40% of the total computational time in a recent profiling of my code).

I want to train a neural network to play this game, requiring thousands of iterations hence I need to make this as fast as possible.

[image]

Comment: Context for this problem would be quite helpful otherwise this problem will likely be closed as it doesn't meet the MSE Guidelines. I don't see a faster way, however, than eliminating the "square vertices" in your graph that don't satisfy your criteria--going through each one-by-one, and then seeing what you have left.

Comment: I have added some more context to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your edits!

Comment: You can maintain the graph of the valid edges (corresponding to movements that are allowed). Each time you make move a tile, you update this graph. For this, you just have to consider edges adjacent to the tile you just added or removed. Then finding the potential places is just a graph traversal, for which there is not much to optimize.